# How to get the item position from custom gridview set in an Adapter class?

Tags: android, gridview, position, onclicklistener, baseadapter

I can fire intent on my button . and  i want to get position or id  of particular view button and pass intent . so pls help? My listview data is parse from web url .

*BaseAdapter class*
//how i can get button position and fire intent

```
public class ListAdapter  extends BaseAdapter{

LayoutInflater inflater;

Context context;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

public ListAdapter(Context context) {

    this.context=context;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int i, View view, final ViewGroup viewGroup) {


    ViewHolder holder;
    if(view == null) {
        // Inflate and initialize your layout
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, viewGroup, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.addsql = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.addsql);

        holder.addsql.setTag(new Integer(i));





        // etc, etc...
        view.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }



    holder.addsql.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Log.d("position is" , ""+view.getTag());
            //Integer i = (Integer)view.getTag();
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "helllllo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return view;
}


}

 class ViewHolder {
    TextView date;
    TextView title;
    TextView price;
    Button addsql;
    Button button;
    int position;
}
```

//these are two buttons  where i set intents to move another activity.
*xml file*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />



<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/price"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ADD SQL"
    android:id="@+id/addsql"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

//In this activity I parse data from web url through JSON .

```
_MainActivity.java_

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "http://www.goteso.com/projects/dinvinguide/api/get_magazines.php";

// JSON Node names




private static final String ID = "id";
private static final String MID = "magazine_id";
private static final String Date="date";
private static final String Title= "title";
private static final String CoverPic = "cover_pic";
private static final String Price= "price";
private static final String Description = "description";
private static final String Halfpdf = "light_pdf";
private static final String Fullpdf = "full_pdf";
private static final String Ios = "ios_app_purchase_id";
private static final String Aos = "android_purchase_id";

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray contact ;
ListView lv;
Button addsql;
   ListAdapter list;
//Context con;

// Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    contactList=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    list = new com.example.gurcharan.jsondemoo.ListAdapter(this);



    // Calling async task to get json
    new GetContacts().execute();


}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {

                contact=new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                //JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
               // String contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);
                String str=contact.getString(0);
                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contact.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contact.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(ID);
                    String date = c.getString(Date);
                    String title = c.getString(Title);
                    String cover_pic = c.getString(CoverPic);
                    String price = c.getString(Price);

                    String description = c.getString(Description);
                    String light_pdf = c.getString(Halfpdf);
                    String full_pdf = c.getString(Fullpdf);
                    String ios_app_purchase_id = c.getString(Ios);
                    String android_purchase_id = c.getString(Aos);


                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

                    contact.put(Date, date);
                    contact.put(Title, title);
                    contact.put(Price, price);
                    //contact.put(CoverPic, cover_pic);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         *
         * */



        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, contactList,
                R.layout.list, new String[] { Date, Title,
                Price }, new int[] { R.id.date,
                R.id.title, R.id.price });



                lv.setAdapter(adapter);




    }


}


}
```

//here list view is set
    _main_activity.xml_

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.gurcharan.jsondemoo.MainActivity">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we Can use ViewHolder class in BaseAdapter and not use SimpleAdapter . We must use that Adapter Which we define to extend a class

Answer (score 0):

add this class in your adapter :

```
private class OnButtonClick implements View.OnClickListener {
    /**
     * @param pos it is your current position
     */
    int pos;

    public OnButtonClick(int pos) {
        this.pos = pos;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // intent from here 
    }
}
```

then define button click event like this :

```
holder.yourbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnButtonClick());
```

Comment: This is not working please read the full code which i update again .

Comment: brother you have setAdapter is SimpleAdapter. and you attached code of adapter of BaseAdapter. How this both can match ?